# Как работают модули в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

У меня есть проект1. Там набор лейаутов, строк и пара классов.
Я хочу сделать проект2 и подключить к нему проект1, как модуль.
Чтобы в итоговом apk файле запускался проект1, но с некоторыми ресурсами из проект2. (отсутствующими в проект1) Ну и в тоже время некоторые ресурсы проект2 ссылаются на ресурсы проект1.
Как правильно это сделать? Ещё хотелось бы, чтобы проект1 в виде модуля можно было использовать из нескольких проектов2. Типа как либу.
Сейчас, Gradle проекта1 ругается, что не может найти ресурсы, которые в основном модуле app (проект2)
File -> invalidate caches не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того , чтобы подключить модуль на основе исходных кодов делаем следующее . В проекте , к которому необходимо подключить модуль :

Импортируете подключаемый модуль в проект:

File -> New -> Import Module

Затем подключаете модуль к основному проекту:

Project Structure -> основной модуль -> вкладка Dependencies -> `+` справа -> Module dependency -> Имя импортированного модуля

В обоих модулях должны совпадать minSDKVersion (файлы build.gradle модулей) и указанные buildToolsVersion должны быть установлены в SDK

Comment: Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Dependency DrawForest:DrawingModule:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: D:\YandexDisc\AndroidApps\DrawForest\DrawingModule\build\outputs\apk\DrawingModule-release-unsigned.apk

Comment: А да .. если вы подключаете модуль , который был приложением , то его надо по другому импортировать , обновил ответ

Comment: Можете просто в `build.gradle` подключаемого модуля поменять `apply plugin:com.android.application` на `apply plugin:com.android.library` и установить одинаковые `minSdkVersion` . Этого должно хватить

Comment: Спасибо, но пока решил попробовать скрипт на питоне для ручной генерации проектов ;D

Comment: если не удаетса то верните plugin:com.android.application и удалите applicationId в подключаемом модуле