# Не выходит подключить проект, как модуль

Tags: android, android-library

Имеется проект на GitHub'e — [проект](https://github.com/wjwarren/dota2-api-wrapper) и мне нужно его подключить в мой проект.

---

Пойдя путем, описанном в каком-то ответе на stackoverflow я попробовал подключить проект так:

File -> New -> Import Module -> Выбрал папку с исходниками проекта. На это AS мне сказала:

> Select modules to import

В импортируемом проекте, в `build.gradle` содержится строка: apply `plugin: "android-library"`

---

Почему Android Studio не видит проект, как модуль и как его подключить?

---

build.gradle (глобальный) моего проекта:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (локальный) моего проекта:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rostislav.dugin.playdotaformoney"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
}
```

build.gradle импортируемого проекта (правился вручную через блокнот, так что ошибки не исключены):

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "1.8"
}

apply plugin: "com.android.library"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        // Android Gradle plugin.
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24

        versionCode = "1"
        versionName = "0.1"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
            java.srcDirs = ["src"]
            res.srcDirs = ["res"]
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Libs:
    // Android API lvl 8
    compile group: "com.google.android", name: "android", version: "2.2.1"
    // GSON
    compile group: "com.google.code.gson", name: "gson", version: "2.2.2"
}
```

Экран импорта модуля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/419064/177345 ?

Comment: @pavlofff, попробовал отредактировать вручную файл, чтобы все SDK version, build tools и т.д. совпадали — ошибка осталась.

Comment: какая ошибка? в вопросе ничего нет о ошибке .. вторую часть ответа вы тоже проделали? совпадать должны только minSDKversion, а если build tools в проектах разные, то оба они должны быть установлены через SDK Manager

Comment: @pavlofff, ошибка — это сообщение `Select modules to import`. Да, проделал. Но, видимо, ручное редактирование — не самая хорошая идея. Сейчас открою своей AS и буду с помощью редактора изменять все.

Comment: эта надпись значит - "выберете модуль для импорта", это не ошибка, а предложение действия, которое вам нужно совершить. В ответ на эту "ошибку" вам нужно указать, где находится присоединяемый проект

Comment: @pavlofff, ну может я и преувеличил, назвав это ошибкой, но там же ничего для выбора нет. Просто путь к проекту и снизу сообщение.

Comment: Скорее всего вы получаете желтый треугольник с надписью "Project already contains module with this name", тогда у вас конфликт имен проектов (например оба имеют имя app) - один из них нужно переименовать.

Comment: @pavlofff, да и имена разные. :(

Comment: прикрепите скриншот этого окна тогда  что ли. Так трудно понять, в чем именно проблема

Comment: @pavlofff, а при попытке начать редактировать вручную все SDK, build и т.д. версии — ругается на все подряд. Мистика какая-то. Вроде и руки не так криво растут :). Попробую обойтись без проекта, благо нашел более-менее адекватное Web API. Ну а если все-таки пригодится проект — буду качать старые SDK, старые гредлы и "поднимать" версии до нормальных .

Comment: посмотрите так же третий пункт [этого ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425671/177345) (module dependency), если все условия оттуда выполнены, проект должен импортироваться без проблем

Comment: @pavlofff, да вроде все верно, но все равно ничего. Давайте я выложу `build.gradle` файлы? Может все-таки что-то упустил.

Comment: При импорте кроме "Select modules to import" вообще ничего не написано?

Comment: @pavlofff, вообще. Фото тоже прикреплю :).

Comment: @pavlofff, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Боюсь что для того, чтобы подключить эту библиотеку нужно призывать разработчиков, у меня не получилось ее импортировать в проект.

Comment: @pavlofff, думаю, ее уже давно забросили. Буду как-то без нее. Но за помощь спасибо. Добавьте в ответ, что ее не выходит подключить,  я приму.

Answer (score 1):

Уверены, что `apply plugin: 'android-library'`?

Я вот смотрю свои проекты, у меня у модулей `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` в build.gradle

Comment: Изменил вручную в блокноте, но не помогло.