# Можно-ли импортировать один проект в другой?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Добрый день.У меня есть приложение.Теперь разрабатываю новое и всё что в этом есть будет там использоваться .Не хочу переписывать огронмый код .Можно ли как то импортировать один проект в другой?И какие способы есть решения данной задачи ?

Comment: Ставите курсор на нужный пакет и `CTRL+C`, `CTRL+V`

Comment: @rjhdby axaxax)))))))))))))))175 классов и около 200 фрагментов ))))нет думаю лучше напистаь с 0 ))

Comment: Ну так поставьте курсор на корневой пакет. В чем трабл то?

Comment: Это не правильный путь

Comment: Спаркуа ли?.... Обоснуй

Comment: Может это будет откровением, но переиспользование кода между проектами происходит именно таким образом. Впрочем хозяин-барин. Всяк сам кузнец своих... гм... проблем.

Comment: Можно подключить как модуль. Посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419064/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

Создайте модуль из вашего текущего проекта, это просто:

```
File -> New -> Import Module -> Выбрать папку или GradleScript
```

Создайте название модуля и всё.

Проверить подключился ли модуль вы можете в `settings.gradle` в корневой папке проекта. Там должно находится несколько, например:

```
include ':app', ':myModule'
```